# How to dynamically differentiate the memcahce instances in java code?

Tags: java, design-patterns, memcached

**Can anyone suggest any design pattern to dynamically differentiate the memcahce instances in java code?**

Previously in my application there is only one memcache instance configured this way

### Step-1:

**dev.memcached.location=33.10.77.88:11211**

**dev.memcached.poolsize=5**

### Step-2:

Then i am accessing that memcache in code as follows,

```
private MemcachedInterface() throws IOException {

    String location =stringParam("memcached.location", "33.10.77.88:11211");

    MemcachedClientBuilder builder = new XMemcachedClientBuilder(AddrUtil.getAddresses(location));

}
```

Then i am invoking that memcache as follows in code using above MemcachedInterface(),

### Step-3:

**MemcachedInterface.getSoleInstance();**

And then i am using that MemcachedInterface() to get/set data as follows,

**MemcachedInterface.set(MEMCACHED_CUSTS, "{}");
resp = MemcachedInterface.gets(MEMCACHED_CUSTS);**

My question is if i introduce an  new memcache instance in our architechture,configuration is done as follows,

### Step-1:

**dev.memcached.location=33.10.77.89:11211
dev.memcached.poolsize=5**

So, first memcache instance is in 33.10.77.88:11211 and second memcache instance is in 33.10.77.89:11211

until this its ok...but....

how to handle Step-2 and Step-3 in this case,To get the MemcachedInterface dynamically.

1)should i use one more interface called MemcachedInterface2()  in step-2

**Now the actual problem comes in,**

I am having 4 webservers in my application.Previoulsy all are writing to MemcachedInterface(),but now as i will introduce one more memcache instance ex:MemcachedInterface2() ws1 and ws2 should write in MemcachedInterface() and ws3 and ws4 should write in ex:MemcachedInterface2()

So,if i use one more interface called MemcachedInterface2()  as mentioned above,

This an code burden as i should change all the classes using WS3 and WS4 to Ex:MemcachedInterface2() .

**Can anyone suggest one approach with limited code changes??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xmemcached supports constistent hashing which will allow your client to choose the right memcached server instance from the pool. You can refer to this answer for a bit more detail [Do client need to worry about multiple memcache servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116293/do-client-need-to-worry-about-multiple-memcache-servers)

So, if I understood correctly, you'll have to

1. use only one memcached client in all your webapps
2. since you have your own wrapper class around the memcached client `MemcachedInterface`, you'll have to add some method to this interface, that enables to add/remove server to an existing client.  See the user guide (scroll down a little): https://code.google.com/p/xmemcached/wiki/User_Guide#JMX_Support

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can see is, you have duplicate code running on different machines as like parallel web services. thus, i recommend this to differentiate each;

1. Use Singleton Facade service for wrapping your memcached client.  (I think you are already doing this)
2. Use Encapsulation. Encapsulate your memcached client for de-couple from your code. `interface L2Cache`
3. For each server, give them a name in global variable. Assign those values via JVM or your own configuration files via  jar or whatever. JVM: `--Dcom.projectname.servername=server-1`
4. Use this global variable as a parameter, configure your Service getInstance method.

> ```
> public static L2Cache getCache() { 
> if (System.getProperty("com.projectname.servername").equals("server-1"))
>    return new L2CacheImpl(SERVER_1_L2_REACHIBILITY_ADDRESSES, POOL_SIZE);
> }
> ```

good luck with your design!

Answer (score 0):

You should list all memcached server instances as space separated in your config.

e.g. 
33.10.77.88:11211 33.10.77.89:11211

So, in your code (**Step2**):

```
private MemcachedInterface() throws IOException 
{
    String location =stringParam("memcached.location", "33.10.77.88:11211 33.10.77.89:11211");
    MemcachedClientBuilder builder = new XMemcachedClientBuilder(AddrUtil.getAddresses(location));
}
```

Then in Step3 you don't need to change anything...e.g. `MemcachedInterface.getSoleInstance();` .

You can read more in memcached tutorial article:

**Use Memcached for Java enterprise performance**, **Part 1**: Architecture and setup
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2012/120418-memcached-for-java-enterprise-performance.html

**Use Memcached for Java enterprise performance, Part 2**: Database-driven web apps
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2012/120515-memcached-for-java-enterprise-performance-2.html